# Remove node in linked list with function taking reference to pointer to a node?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, reference, nodes

Consider an implemented `struct Node`:

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    Node<T> * next;
    T data;
    // Other functions for adding nodes etc...
};
```

Then a function `remove(...)` is given, which takes the parameters 1) **reference to pointer to node** `p` and 2) the data `d` to be removed:

```
template <class T>
void remove(Node<T> *& p, T d) {
    if (p != nullptr) {
        if (p->data == d) {
            Node<T> * temp = p;
            p = p->next;
            delete temp;
            remove(p, d);
        }
        else {
            remove(p->next, d);
        };
    };
};
```

**Questions**

I don't quite understand how this will work. Since `temp` points to `p`, won't the assigned `p=p->next` be removed anyhow in `delete temp`, making this function fail? Is there something I'm missing? Perhaps something to do with that the pointer `p` is passed as a reference?

Thank you.

Comment: No as temp and p have different values i.e. points to different nodes as p is re-assigned to point to the next node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since temp points to `p`, won't the assigned `p=p->next` be removed
>   anyhow in delete temp, making this function fail?

`temp` doesn't point to `p` but to what `p` points. Note that the pointers are vars having addressees as values and when a pointer on the rhs it returns its value.

And the assignment `p = p -> next` makes the value of `p` be the address of the of the node after `p` (i.e) the address returned by `p -> next`

Comment: Thank you! So, since `p` is passed to the function `remove` as a reference to the pointer to the node, we get the node's pointer's address in memory. We then change the value at that address to the be the pointer to the next node object in the linked list instead, i.e. `p = p->next`. Previous to that we have assigned `temp` to point to the actual "old" node object which `p` held the address for, and delete it?

Comment: @Defindun Yes. the tricky part in passing by reference is to change the value (the address held by the pointer) of the pointer itself. If you passed it by value you wouldn't be able to change the value of the pointer in your list but you would change the value held by an automatic pointer.